# How to install ffmpeg using xampp

Tags: php, apache, ffmpeg, php-extension, shell-exec

I am trying to install ffmpeg onto my localhost server. I have followed countless blogs and tutorials online form other people who are stuck with this same problem. I follow everything to the letter.

1. Unzip the file
2. Copy php_ffmpeg.exe to ext folder in php
3. copy the rest to system 32

As it says however when I do this I get this error when I start apache.

[image: error message]

Fair play but it is in the folder

[image: Here is my file]

I also get this error as well:

[image: Second error]

And Again, here it is:
[image: second file placement]

I have added the extention to my php.ini file

> extension=php_ffmpeg.dll

The first time I go this to work I placed the ffmpeg.exe file onto my local host server and ran commands like this:

```
$cmd = "$ffmpegpath -i $input -an -ss $sec -s $size $output";
shell_exec($cmd);
```

This works fine on my computer but not on an actual server. Could somebody offer some advice or guidene on where I have one wrong installing the extension or why running the .exe file on a lunix server with shell_exec doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Yeah ive had problems with the extension version, with windows. I found it is much easier to not use the PHP extension and just call the standard FFMPEG for windows binary with exec() within a simple class, ive added an example script. It will be trivial for you to add a `ffmpeg_convert()` method to the class.

[VideoThumbNailer.example.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kkvr92e1ryphbi8/VideoThumbNailer.example.zip)

### Edit

Just noticed this statement,

> Could somebody offer some advice or guidene on where I have one wrong
>   installing the extension or why running the .exe file on a lunix
>   server with shell_exec doesn't work

Linux has its own versions of FFMPEG, you cant mix the two. Your need to install FFMPEG on linux with something like:

```
sudo apt-get -qqy php5-ffmpeg
```

And change the path to FFMPEG in your cmd to, leaving out the .exe part:

`ffmpeg -i $input -an -ss $sec -s $size $output`

Hope it helps